# How parse data with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need help in parsing out the following data.

---

**Data to parse:**

2014-09-08 00:00:00:000

2014-09-15 00:00:00:000

2005-12-12 00:00:00:000

I have already created a piece of code to parse the month.

```
  var dohMonth = jQuery(this.attr("ows_DOH").split('-')[1];
```

The above code will create the following output:

09

09

12

Now I need help creating a piece of code for parsing the actual day of the month.

If I use:

```
var dohDay = jQuery(this).attr("ows_DOH").split('-')[2];
```

It will create the following output:

08 00:00:00:000

15 00:00:00:000

12 00:00:00:000

The extra zeros (The time format) are what I do not need.

I would like it to just be:

08

15

12

Any suggestions on how I should go about this ?

Comment: Are you parsing because you want to work with dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning the text into a javascript date object and then extracting out the data should do it for you.

```
var tempDate = new Date(jQuery(this).attr("ows_DOH"));
var dohDay = tempDate.getDate();
var dohMonth = tempDate.getMonth() + 1; // 0 indexed
var dohYear = tempDate.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your first split on the blank space ' ', this will give you the date and time as separate pieces. Then just split the date on '-' to get the year, month, and day.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the date by splitting the remaining text again with respect to the spaces and then extracting the 0th element.

```
var dohDay = (jQuery(this).attr("ows_DOH").split('-')[2]).split(' ')[0];
```

But rather than extracting the date components from a string, you should consider converting that string to a Javascript Date/Time Object. You could then use the predefined functions to extract individual date components directly rather than splitting this string multiple times.